# How to open fragment from the click of the notification?

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, fragment

This is my onMessageReceived method. I am getting data from notification i want to open fragment when i click on this notification and get the data from this.

```
  @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d("Firebase Push Received", "Frommm: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d("Firebase Push Received", "Notification " +
                " Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());


        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // AGREGO EN EL PAYLOAD LA VARIABLE DATA PARA QUE APAREZCA EN EL FOREGROUND, SINO LEE LA VAR NOTIFICATION DEL PAYLOAD
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            String type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
            String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
            String id = remoteMessage.getData().get("id");
            Log.d(TAG, "type" + type);
            Log.d(TAG, "id" + id);


            Log.d(TAG, "notidata" + remoteMessage.getData());

            boolean flag = false;
            Intent notificationIntent;
            /*SharedPreferences notificationStatus = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.NotificationStatus, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String status = notificationStatus.getString("status", "");

            if (status.equals("true")) {
                flag = true;
                notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            } else {
                notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), StarterActivity.class);
            }
            if (flag) {
                notificationIntent.addCategory((Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER));
                notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            }*/
            notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

            notificationIntent.putExtra("id", id);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("type", type);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("isfrom", "notification");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("lessonId", id);
            bundle.putString("type1", type);
            bundle.putString("isfrom", "notification");

            /*PendingIntent contentIntent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_home)
                    .setDestination(R.id.playerController)
                    .setArguments(bundle)
                    .createPendingIntent();*/
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getResources().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.headblack)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .build();

            NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getResources().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), getResources().getString(R.string.channel_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            manager.notify(R.string.default_notification_channel_id, notification);

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MessageNotificationBody: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
```

This is my main activity..

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
                if (!isTaskRoot() && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                    && getIntent().getAction() != null
                    && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
            ) {
                finish();
                processIntent(getIntent());
                return;
            }
    
            SharedPreferences notificationStatus = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.NotificationStatus, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = notificationStatus.edit();
            edit.putString("status", "true");
            edit.apply();
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.spin_kit);
            progressBarHolder = findViewById(R.id.progressBarHolder);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    
            final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.hide();
            navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
    
            AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                    R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_lessons, R.id.navigation_prematch, R.id.navigation_journals, R.id.navigation_move)
                    .build();
    
            navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    
        }
    


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        processIntent(intent);
    }
    


private void processIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            //   checkStatus();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            id = intent.getExtras().get("id").toString();

            type = intent.getExtras().get("type").toString();
}
        }
```

**From process intent i want to open my fragment using navcontroller but it open the mainactivity and load the home fragment instead the the playerfragment that i want to implement on click of the notification.**

The player fragment is  in the nav graph of the main activity.

Most of the stack overflow answers contain the navdeeplink that doesnt work here it openes the main activity and load the data of the main activity instead the destination.

> Anyone how to open a fragment when user click on the notification when activity is running and when activity is in the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user tries to open notification and tries to open the fragment he want to load the data i tried this way and it performed well.. even when app was closed and even when the app is running it is working.

**MainActivity**

> in on create

```
      Intent intent = getIntent();
                       if(intent !=null&&intent.getExtras()!=null)
                       {
                            id = intent.getExtras().get("id").toString();
                            type = intent.getExtras().get("type").toString();
//here i check if data is not null then i proceed to pass the data to the fragment using nav controller i defined earlier. 
                            bundle.putString("lessonId", id);
                            bundle.putString("type", type);
                            bundle.putLong("lastPosition", Math.round(lastPosition));
                            navController.navigate(R.id.player, bundle);
                        }
```

> this works when I try to click the notification when the app is open,
> but when the app is not open it doesn't fetch the data from intent
> because it isn't the starter app.

so i did the same process in splash activity and got the data from notification from that and i passed that data into main activity from where the fragment is being called.

Thank you so much guys for quick support..!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to open fragment from notifications.
In the notification pending intent add putextras and get it in activity and navigate corresponding fragment

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("redirect", "homefragment");
```

In your activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      String value= intent.getExtras().get("redirect").toString();
      if(value=="homefragment")
       {
              // redirect your fragment
       }
```

Comment: When activity is open already it just opens activity again and it crashes. it says from this nav graph destination is not found. and when app is in background it just opens main activity and   nothing happens.

Comment: What error you get @JAY_Panchal?

Comment: @JAY_Panchal , that is because Fragment you are trying to reach is not in your current Nav Graph. You need to change your current Destination Graph by `findNavController().navigate(R.id.desiredGraph)`. After that, redirect to your fragment

Comment: yes Actually i found the problem the the fragmnet was in nested graph ..

Comment: @sasikumar  it works only when the user already in app doesnt work when user has killed the app

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **Explicit Deep Links** in Navigation Architecture.

You can check this article to proceed with it:
[Navigating with Deep Links](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigating-with-deep-links-910a4a6588c)

You should also check [Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link). They provide in-depth description of what's going on internally